# Add Logo & Title to NavBar (Yii2)

Tags: yii2, navbar

How can I add a logo + title to a Yii2 web app?

I used concatenation to stick logo to title (as below)

```
 NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => '<img src="favicon-32x32.png"; class="img-responsive">'.'Car Management System',
```

and it worked but the logo appeared on top of the title.
Is this a wrong way to make it?
Or is it right but it needs some style properties changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See if this works for you, it just changes the `<img>` syntax to be correct:

```
'brandLabel' => '<img src="favicon-32x32.png" class="img-responsive"/>Car Management System',
```

If you are having problems with the image and the text not sitting on the same line, you probably want to replace the `img-responsive` class with the `pull-left` class... or just remove the `img-responsive` class and it may start working (depending on the styles already applied to the image). Example:

```
'brandLabel' => '<img src="favicon-32x32.png" class="pull-left"/>Car Management System',
```

Comment: It doesn't work because "brand" is actually not a property of NavBar.

Comment: Is this the Bootstrap NavBar widget? Must've looked at docs for a different version of the widget - will update the answer.

Comment: Yes it is a Bootstrap widget.

Comment: Does the new version of the code work? If not, please post a screenshot of what it looks like for you.

Comment: your solution gives an error (as I said above) that Brand is undefined property.

Comment: Well I didn't see the updated code till now.. Thanks a lot, it worked when it used pull-left

Comment: No problem. Sometimes edited answers don't seem to refresh very well. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, in addition I have a square image of `48x48`. I have solved it like your initial solution but with the help of the following `style` attribute's values:

```
...
'brandLabel' => '<img src="logo.png" style="display:inline; vertical-align: top; height:32px;">My Company',
...
```

The final result is shown in the following screen shot:

[image]